# Props not transferring to Grand-Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to pass a prop function from a Parent to a Child but I can't seem to pass it from Child to Grand-Child.

The code in question:

```js
var ProposalList = React.createClass({

    render : function() {

        var proposalNode = this.props.data.map(function(proposal) {
            return (
                <ProposalItem submitForm={this.props.submitForm} id={proposal.id} name={proposal.name} price={proposal.price}/>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div><ul className="proposalList">{proposalNode}</ul></div>
        );
    }

});
```

The line that is conflicting is a child called "ProposalItem" and the prop that is being identify as undefined is: submitForm={this.props.submitForm} or "submitForm".

ProposalList is rendering fine though.

```js
<ProposalList submitForm={this.loadFromServer} data={this.state.data} />
```

I can't seem to grab submitForm and pass it to the next component child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), note that what is `this` now, you forget to pass the `thisArg` to `map`, so `this` should be `window` or something else, not the react component you expect.

```
var proposalNode = this.props.data.map(function (proposal) {
    return (
        <ProposalItem submitForm={this.props.submitForm} id={proposal.id} name={proposal.name} price={proposal.price}/>
            );
}, this);
// ^^^^ add this param.
```

should work.

Or you can use `var self = this;`, then use `self.props.submitForm` in map callback, or use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the map's callback function to the react component.